# How to serialize a decimal value (double) to a uint32 in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, unsigned

So far I've been using the following code to convert signed to unsigned values that I need to send as a byte array over UDP to an embedded system.

```
   public static byte serializeShort(short a)
{
    return ((byte) (a & 0xFF));
}

public static short serializeInt(int a)
{
    return ((short) (a & 0xFFFF));
}

public static int serializeLong(long a)
{
    return ((int) (a & 0xFFFFFFFF));
}
```

The issue with the long, is some values can be real values. The output of this method I put into a bytebuffer via put(), putInt(), or putShort().

Any idea on how to translate the signed to unsigned for a double type?

Specifically here is my problem:

I have a UINT32 value that is being populated. I'm filling in my byte buffer with either a java signed LONG or a java signed double. I used the 'serializeLong()' above for the longs and it works fine, but the doubles do not.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);
if (value instanceof Long)
    {
        buffer.putInt(Util.serializeLong((Long) value));
    } else
    {
        buffer.putInt(Util.serializeLong(Double.doubleToLongBits((Double) value)));
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? I assume you have tried the obvious but this isn't right so what is the problem?

Comment: BTW `((byte) (a & 0xFF))` is the same as `(byte) a`

Comment: Why are you serializing to half-size? You can't do that. Besides, all you'd have to do is cast, because Java's [**narrowing** primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) will do what you want.

Comment: All these are going back and forth from UINT8, UINT16, UINT32 to a java object and back, so when I'm writing them back, I need to convert the value back to unsigned and reduce it so that it fits in the available byte range.

Comment: You might be looking for `Double.doubleToLongBits(double)`.

Comment: You, sir, are my bloody hero. Well done. That works swimmingly.

Comment: Actually... oddly enough I put in 9.1 to the Double.doubleToLongBits(9.1) and print out and get 4621312462630892339...

Comment: @Tacitus86 It converts the double to a long so that you can serialize it or manipulate it's bits. If you want to round the double you could try `Math.round(double)`.

Comment: Well I skipped a step I have a Double a = 9.1 and put it into that function. It seems the embedded machine is getting a crazy number as well. The guy who runs that left for the day so I can't compare to what I'm seeing, but he's def not getting the uint32 version of 9.1

Comment: This is not serializing . This is data conversion. Unclear why you would want to do this in the first place and lose all that precision and range. `double` is not a 'decimal value'. There is no such thing as 'the `uint32` value of 9.1'. Are you perhaps looking for `float`? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps float will work for this, but some of the possible values were failing compare checks due to the sci notation and big numbers.

Comment: Reason is that the data is going over UDP to an embedded system that has a predefined size of uint32 in the message for this value which will have a decimal.

Comment: The size is not the only issue. There is also the minor question of format. What format is the device expecting this data in?

Comment: Its BigEndian if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: A little more as to what Im doing is reading in UDP messages in a particular format, the value being a uint32, which I read into a Double type for java to manipulate and store this in a buffer of type T. Client can send a change request with a new value which will be either long (2567431) or real (1.0000005) random examples. I need to compare this with previous value to see if there is a change and then convert this back to a byte string to return to the system via UDP (uint32), while maintaining the real/long format.

Comment: All parts of this is working already except being able to convert the real values back to a uint32.

Comment: Big-endian is a part of what I'm asking. How does the fractional part of the `double` go into the `uint32`? It really sounds like you're looking for `float` to me. NB You can't get scientific notation into a `uint32`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Im not really sure tbh. I read it out of the same format, I guess my question IS how to get it into the uint32...

Comment: You read it out if the same format how? You're not going to get an answer until you state what the format actually is.

Comment: I read the udp in as a byte string which i piece apart into primitive objects based on known size.

Comment: Oh come off it. You read 32 bits which you somehow magically convert into a floating-point number. What is that process? You aren't making the slightest attempt to help yourself here.

Comment: currentValueArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 0, 4);
    currentValue = Util.reassembleLong(currentValueArray);

public static long reassembleLong(byte[] input)
    {

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        long result = getUnsignedLong(buffer);
        return result;
    }

public static long getUnsignedLong(ByteBuffer bb)
    {
        return ((long) bb.getInt() & 0xffffffffL);
    }

Comment: I found my own solution. It's really sad how hostile this forum has gotten. When someone doesn't understand, it would be nice to try to be more helpful, not assume the person is being lazy or arrogant.

Comment: You 'found your own solution' that had been suggested to you *four days ago*. When you consistently fail to provide useful information it is inevitable that the temperature is going . Ask yourself. What information have you provided here that would lead to your solution? Exactly none. You had plenty of opportunity. You were also badly at fault for describing the field as a `uint32` in the first place.

Comment: Yep, ridicule the guy who asked for help. Thanks for nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using a Double, you should be using a float and to get it into the uint32 space use: buffer.putInt((Float.floatToRawIntBits(Math.abs((Float) value))));

Comment: You ignored exactly that suggestion when it was made four days ago.